# How long could you survive in Space without a Spacesuit?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, vacuum, space

**Contrary to popular belief, and numerous Hollywood movies, you could survive unprotected in space for over a minute - provided you could get back to medical care immediately after.**

Moreover, in movies we see astronauts and people in spaceships opening doors and closing them again with no suits on.

**Are these things correct or just myths?
Is there any way to estimate or predict the time for the above?**

Comment: Im not sure whether it makes sense to ask this on the physics stack exchange because it seems to me to be more about biology than physics